# Remove everything that comes after a word that is after a specific word in Python

Tags: python

I have few strings like:

```
This is a beautiful string 1 - written by a dog
This is a beautiful string 2 written by a fly
This is a beautiful string 3 ewh
```

With python, I want to remove everything that comes after string X. After filtration I want the string to be:

```
This is a beautiful string 1
This is a beautiful string 2
This is a beautiful string 3
```

There can be anything after "string", it's not necessary that it'll be a number.

Is this possible?

I looked for ways of doing this and found .rsplit() but it didn't work the way I expected.

Comment: So what should be the result of for example `This is a beautiful string string string`?

Comment: Result should be: `This is a beautiful string 1` then `..string 2` and `..string 3`.

Comment: Wait so even if there is no number in the original string you want to have one at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess simple regexp will do the job:

```
import re

p = re.compile("string \d+")
for line in lines:
    if resp := p.search(line):
        print(line[0:resp.end()])
    else:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.match` or `re.findall`:

```
import re

string1 = 'This is a beautiful string 1 - written by a dog'
string2 = 'This is a beautiful string 2 written by a fly'
string3 = 'This is a beautiful string 3 ewh'
string4 = 'This is a beautiful string whatever by me'

res1 = re.match('(.*string \w+)', string1)[0]
res2 = re.findall('(.*string \w+)', string2)[0]
res3 = re.match('(.*string \w+)', string3)[0]
res4 = re.findall('(.*string \w+)', string4)[0]

print(res1), print(res2), print(res3), print(res4)

# This is a beautiful string 1
# This is a beautiful string 2
# This is a beautiful string 3
# This is a beautiful string whatever
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is your string

```
 x = """This is a beautiful string 1 - written by a dog
    This is a beautiful string 2 written by a fly
    This is a beautiful string 3 ewh"""
```

For single line:

```
print(x.replace((x[x.index("g")+3:]), ""))
```

output:

```
This is a beautiful string 1
```

For everyline:

```
print([y.replace((y[y.index("g")+3:]), "") for y in x.splitlines()])
```

output:

```
['This is a beautiful string 1', 'This is a beautiful string 2', 'This is a beautiful string 3']
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo The questioners' concern is not about anything before the string but after. " This is a beautiful string " is a common line

Comment: This is just an example for the question...

Answer (score -2):

```
x=This is a beautiful string 1 - written by a dog
y=This is a beautiful string 2 written by a fly
z=This is a beautiful string 3 ewh

list=[x,y,z]

string=[]
new_list=[]
for i in range (1,len(list)+1):
    sep='string {}'.format(i)
    string=list[i-1].split(sep,1)[0]+sep
    new_list.append(string)

new_list
```

**Output**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDP80.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: From the question: *"There can be anything after "string", it's not necessary that it'll be a number."*